# Intercepting Oracle raise_application_error custom messages within Microsoft Access?

Tags: oracle, ms-access, exception, error-handling, adodb

**Summary**

I have an Oracle procedure with a similar EXCEPTION block as what is below.  I want to pass the output of raise_application_error back to Microsoft Access and display it to the user.  It is Microsoft Access calling this Oracle Procedure.

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN e_invalidids THEN
    raise_application_error (-20001,'Invalid ids in Upload Table.');
  WHEN e_missingdate THEN
    raise_application_error (-20002,'Missing Date in Upload Table.');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    raise_application_error (-20000,'An error was encountered - ' || SQLCODE || ' -ERROR- ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

**Request**

I want to be pointed in the right direction - given a method to report this error back within Access.

If the solution is to turn the Oracle Procedure into a Function - then I would like someone to touch on how to do that *properly* (ie. trapping for an exception and then returning the value)

**Background Info**

I am writing a userland tool to import data into an Oracle database, using an Access Database as a front end.  The data is imported from Excel, cleaned up, corrected, and tested against a variety of validation checks.   Access then uses ADO to write the data to a table on the Oracle server, and then invoke a PL/SQL procedure to process it.

The procedure performs a number of validation checks (some are duplicate, some are specific to the DB).  When passed, it reads in each record - interprets it - and populates the normalized tables in the database.

Considering the amount of validation checks already at play in Access, I am really not expecting any errors to be raised from the Oracle Procedure - but if there is, I'd like the error to be passed back to Access and displayed to the user.

**What I've tried**

I have searched on this forum, and Google.  From what I read - raise_application_error returns output to the calling client - but given that there is an OLE DB Provider and the ADO DB API between Oracle and Access, I am guessing that the error is being encapsulated and a simple Pass/Fail is being returned from the Execute call:

```
oraConn.Execute "import_data"
oraErrText = ""
Set oraErrors = oraConn.Errors

For Each oraError In oraErrors
  debug.print oraError.Number
  debug.print oraError.Description
  debug.print oraError.Source
  debug.print oraError.SQLState 
  debug.print oraError.NativeError
Next
```

The above results in a single error:   **ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending two weeks trying various things - it started working.  I had a feeling it had to do with using the OLEDB Provider as opposed to the ODBC driver, and the stored procedure command text.  I had also moved my stored procedure into a package.

**Oracle Setup**

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE test AS
  PROCEDURE testSP;
END test;
/
create or replace 
PACKAGE BODY test AS
  PROCEDURE testSP IS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE
      e_test EXCEPTION;
    BEGIN
      RAISE e_test;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN e_test THEN
        raise_application_error (-20001,'Test Error');
        RETURN;
    END;
  END;
END test;
```

**VBA Code:**

```
Public Sub testSP(dbCredDSN As String, dbCredUser As String, dbCredPW As String)
  Dim oraConn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim oraCmd As ADODB.Command
  Dim oraError As ADODB.Error

  Set oraConn = New ADODB.Connection

  ' Open our Connection
  Set oraConn = New ADODB.Connection
  oraConn.Mode = adModeReadWrite
  oraConn.Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
  oraConn.Properties("Data Source") = dbCredDSN
  oraConn.Properties("User ID") = dbCredUser
  oraConn.Properties("Password") = dbCredPW
  oraConn.Open

   ' Set up our Command.
  Set oraCmd = New ADODB.Command
  Set oraCmd.ActiveConnection = oraConn
  oraCmd.CommandText = "{CALL test.testSP()}"
  On Error Resume Next
  oraCmd.Execute
  On Error GoTo 0

  For Each oraError In oraConn.Errors
    Debug.Print "Number:       " & oraError.Number
    Debug.Print "Description:  " & oraError.Description
    Debug.Print "Source:       " & oraError.Source
    Debug.Print "SQL State:    " & oraError.SQLState
    Debug.Print "Native Error: " & oraError.NativeError
  Next

  ' Close the Recordset & Connection Objects
  oraConn.Close

  ' Clean Up
  Set oraConn = Nothing
  Set oraCmd = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Execution:**

```
testSP "myDSN","myUsername","myPassword"

Number:       -2147217900
Description:  ORA-20001: Test Error
ORA-06512: at "TESTSERVER.TEST", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 1
Source:       OraOLEDB
SQL State:    
Native Error: 20001
```